# Oracle APEX: Update Table based on changes in an Interactive Grid

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

currently i am facing a problem on how to update a single row in an interactive grid.  am trying to update the table (Interactive Grid) based on the changes the user has made.
 I followed the guide from APEX 5.1. 
Unfortunately the rowid function didn't work.

My code:

```
update poc_sofortmassnahme  
    set BESCHREIBUNG_SOFORT  = :BESCHREIBUNG_SOFORT,  
        BEARBEITER_SOFORT = :BEARBEITER_SOFORT,
        ZIELDATUM_SOFORT = :ZIELDATUM_SOFORT,
        WIRKSAMKEIT = :WIRKSAMKEIT
  where rowid  = :ROWID; // doesn't update the row.
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Sample Code from Oracle APEX 5.1]

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Grid can be editable (as *tabular forms* used to be in previous versions), so I'd suggest you to use that functionality instead of reinventing the wheel. Because, it seems that you're trying to do your own *row processing* while there's no need to do that.

Comment: I already made the Interactive Grid editable, but the Update doesn't work. As I said I followed the guide. My main problem is that the rowid doesn't process properly

Comment: There's nothing to "follow", really. If the Interactive Grid is editable, you modify values in the grid and press the "Save" button. Apex does the rest (i.e. stores values into a table). You don't have to write any code.

Comment: Well, I am not using the toolbar to save. I have multiple IGs on my table and I don't want the user to press everytime on save. Therefore I created three buttons for the save, the update and the delete of records

Comment: So, instead of clicking on one "Save" button (which already exists in the toolbar), you created 3 buttons and let them choose which one to click? I wouldn't call that an *improvement*, but hey - it is your application, do whatever you want. Which, finally, means that I can't assist. Hopefully, someone else will. Good luck!